# Xray robot framework integration linking user story

Tags: robotframework, jira, jira-xray, x-ray

when I am adding user story in tags of automated test cases will the test cases create under the story by linking..currently it's creating new test cases with label as story I'd..not linking to the user story

Manually created test cases

Comment: Can you pease provide more details for the readers? 1) an example of the test results file that you're using, 2) the report format that you're using 3) the endpoint that you're using to submit results, 4) whether it's Jira datacenter or cloud, 5) a screenshot of the Test issue created in Jira, 6) a screenshot of the user story issue screen in Jira that it should have linked to

Comment: Were you able to resolve your question? If not, can you please the information I requested ealier to see if we are able to help you out?